# Как можно избавиться от проблемы, что переменная не определена? Спасибо!

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def a1():
    x = a + 10
    print(x)

def b1():
    a = 10

b1()
a1()
```

Как можно избавиться от проблемы, что a не определено? Спасибо!

Comment: прочитать в учебнике про области видимости. Это обязательно. Так как вариантов может быть много, например, определять `a` в `__main__` (основном) коде.

Comment: Спасибо! Но мне нужно чтобы a определялось именно в другой функции.. Можно ли это как то реализовать?

Comment: Хорошо - см. ответ, но учебник все равно почитайте. Иначе жизнь ваша, как программиста, будет загадочной и странной.

Comment: Я на 100% уверен, что вам просто кажется, что нужно, чтобы переменная определялась в данной функции. Вы думаете, что это вам поможет, хотя наверняка есть и другие способы рулета вашей проблемы, какой бы она ни была.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прочитайте в учебнике про области видимости обязательно. И про функции подробно.

Вариант 1 (очень плохой, никогда так не делайте без очень веской причины):

```
def a1():
    x = a + 10
    print(x)

def b1():
    global a
    a = 10

b1()
a1()
```

Вариант 2 (получше):

```
def a1():
    x = a + 10
    print(x)

def b1():
    a = 10

b1()
a = 5
a1()
```

Вариант 3 (поближе к вашей идее):

```
def a1():
    x = a + 10
    print(x)

def b1():
    a = 10
    return a

a = b1()
a1()
```

Вариант 4 (шутливый):

```
def a1():
    a = 7
    x = a + 10
    print(x)

def b1():
    a = 10

b1()
a1()
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Правда! Только учусь, так что многого не знаю) но обязательно восполню необходимые знания!

Comment: Не за что. Если этот ответ полный, то галку поставьте. Она важнее плюса, так как показывает, что в базе  знаний ответ на вопрос принят.